# Light and fan not working - is the wiring correct?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

So I've come home today to see that the bathroom light and fan is not switching on.

Having unscrewed the switch, I can see this:

[image]

Now it looks like the earth has come completely off, but I wouldn't expect that to have caused the light and fan not to work...or am I wrong here?

Do I connect the earth into the only obvious connector?

Comment: Did you check the breaker or fuse on the circuit?

Comment: @ArchonOSX - yep tht was the first thing I checked.

Comment: That looks like a light only. Is the fan a separate unit?

Comment: Chances are the ground was never connected. Light fixtures didn't have ground wires until the last few decades. I can't tell from the photo whether there's a ground connection on that one. At any rate, it's not the cause of your problem.

Comment: Does the switch feel any different? I wonder if it's worn out and not making contact.

Answer (score 1):

> **it looks like the earth has come completely off, but I wouldn't expect that to have caused the light and fan not to work...or am I wrong here?**

No, you are correct, the earth is not needed here as there are no extraneous conducting parts exposed.

The earth wire, or circuit protective conductor (CPC) is a safety element and does not affect normal operation of the circuit when there is no other fault present.

Switch housings are normally plastic and non-conductive. If the fixed part of yours is conductive metal, the earth wire should be connected to it. Otherwise I would leave it alone.

> **Do I connect the earth into the only obvious connector?**

No, at least not if you think the normally-connected side of the switch is an obvious connector. That would be a recipe for tripping a breaker or setting fire to things.

You could, after turning the breaker off,  remove the wires from the switch completely and then test for continuity across those terminals using a continuity tester or multimeter. This would tell you if the switch is OK. If it is, I would reconnect the wires firmly and look elsewhere for the problem.

It is likely that the red wire is a permanent live and the black is a switched live (an unhelpfully inventive electrician may have wired it vice versa) - if so, the black wire should have red tape around it to indicate it is switched-live and not neutral.